# Inject initiated object with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to set a singletone dependency injection of a handler class.

This handler class gets credentials from a vendor at startup, therefore I need that all requests for my ISomething class should actually return the initiated object.

For instance, in .Net Core you could do this:

```
x.Services.AddSingleton<ISomething, Something>(provider =>
    {
        var something= new Something()
        something.credentials = "credentials"
        return something;
    }
);
```

How could this be done in .Net Framework 4.7.2 & Unity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i remember correctly then you can do:

```
x.Services.RegisterInstance<ISomething>(instance);
```

Where 'instance' is the initialized Something